# How Do I Round Date Figures to the nearest Month in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

2015-01-28T01:45:31.000Z

I want to round the column values for date to the nearest month. 
Is there a way I can do that with a SELECT statement?

Comment: Explain briefly question.

Comment: How do you define "nearest" month?  Does it ever round up?

Answer (score 3):

The statement below will round the date to the 1st of the current month if the day is less than 16, otherwise the date will be rounded to the 1st of the next month.

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN date_format(myDate, '%d') < '16' THEN
           date_format(myDate, '%Y-%m-01')
         ELSE
           date_format( DATE_ADD(myDate, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) , '%Y-%m-01')
         END as 'date_rounded'
  FROM my_table;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select date_format(date_field, '%Y-%m') as date_rounded
```